# How can I split a dictionary in several dictionaries based on a part of values using Python

Tags: python

I have a dictionary like the following

```
dict={'sku1':'k-1','sku2':'k-2','sku3':'b-10','sku4':'b-1','sku5':'x-1', 'sku6':'x-2'}
```

How can I get separate dictionaries based on first letter of value? like:

```
dict1={'sku5':'x-1','sku6':'x-2'}
dict2={'sku1':'k-1','sku2':'k-2'}
dict2={'sku3':'b-10','sku4':'b-1'}
```

I started with

```
for an_item in thevalues_ofdict:
    Splitted_Pcodes.append(int(an_item.split("-")[0]))
    for i in Splitted_Pcodes:
        if i=='x':
```

but how I will find the whole initial dicitonary element

Comment: yes in string 'x-1' , 'k-2'

Comment: Are those supposed to be in a list or seperate variables?

Comment: I have a list with the keys and a list with the values

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this is what you want to do, in a sense. The result is one main ('mother') dictionary that has as keys all possible first letters, and as values the corresponding dicts.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
d = {'sku1': 'k-1','sku2': 'k-2','sku3': 'b-10' ,'sku4': 'b-1', 'sku5': 'x-1', 'sku6':'x-2'}

mother = defaultdict(dict)
for key, val in d.items():
    mother[val[0]][key] = val

mother = dict(mother)
print(mother)
```

Output:

```
{'k': {'sku1': 'k-1', 'sku2': 'k-2'},
 'b': {'sku3': 'b-10', 'sku4': 'b-1'},
 'x': {'sku5': 'x-1', 'sku6': 'x-2'}}
```

You can then make them easily accessible like so.

```
k_dict = mother['k']
b_dict = mother['b']
x_dict = mother['x']
```

---

If you want more control and want to be able to give the size of key, we can do it like so:

```py
from collections import defaultdict


def split_d(d, key_size=1):
    if key_size < 1:
        raise ValueError("'key_size' must be 1 or more")

    mother = defaultdict(dict)
    for key, val in d.items():
        mother[val[0:key_size]][key] = val

    return dict(mother)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = {'sku1': 'k-1','sku2': 'k-2','sku3': 'b-10' ,'sku4': 'b-1', 'sku5': 'x-1', 'sku6':'x-2'}

    res = split_d(d, 3)
    print(res)
```

Comment: Is it possible to have them in separate dictionary variables?

Comment: If you know the variable names that you will need, then yes. See my update.

Comment: In mother[val[0]][key] , 0 is the first character?

Comment: Yes, exactly! So you get the value from the input dictionary and then get that first character of the value.

Comment: If it was 'abc-1' and set it to 2 I get 'c' Can I use some range? from 0::2?

Comment: @brentertainer Of course, that's why I cast it back to a dict.

Comment: Thank you it is very complete!

Comment: @MariaGeorgali I added a snippet to show how we can do this by adding a parameter to the function. Based on that you can make the key longer.

Answer (score 1):

```
from pprint import pprint

dict={'sku1':'k-1','sku2':'k-2','sku3':'b-10','sku4':'b-1','sku5':'x-1', 'sku6':'x-2'}

newdict = {}
for key, val in dict.items():
    v = val[0]
    if v not in newdict:
        newdict[v] = {}
    newdict[v][key] = val

pprint(newdict, indent=4)
```

Output:

```
{   'b': {'sku3': 'b-10', 'sku4': 'b-1'},
    'k': {'sku1': 'k-1', 'sku2': 'k-2'},
    'x': {'sku5': 'x-1', 'sku6': 'x-2'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you shouldn't name your dictionary "dict", as that will mess with pythons dict funciton.

```
my_dict = {'sku1':'k-1','sku2':'k-2','sku3':'b-10','sku4':'b-1','sku5':'x-1', 'sku6':'x-2'}
```

Here's a list comprehension that returns a list of the dicts:

```
[{k:v for (k,v) in my_dict.items() if v[0] == start_val} for start_val in {val[0] for val in my_dict.values()}]
```

Output:

```
 [{'sku5': 'x-1', 'sku6': 'x-2'},
 {'sku3': 'b-10', 'sku4': 'b-1'},
 {'sku1': 'k-1', 'sku2': 'k-2'}]
```

It doesn't handle the dynamic dictionary names but that doesn't seem to be the point of the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
import string
all_dict = {'sku1': 'k-1', 'sku2': 'k-2', 'sku3': 'b-10', 'sku4': 'b-1', 'sku5': 'x-1', 'sku6': 'x-2'}
alphabet_list = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
list_of_new_dict = []
for char in alphabet_list:
    temp_dict = dict()
    for key, value in all_dict.items():
        if value[0]==char:
            temp_dict[key] = value
    if temp_dict:
        list_of_new_dict.append(temp_dict)
```

outout:

```
[{'sku3': 'b-10', 'sku4': 'b-1'}, {'sku1': 'k-1', 'sku2': 'k-2'}, {'sku5': 'x-1', 'sku6': 'x-2'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a straightforward approach using `itertools.groupby` where you can group by the first character of each value (`pair[1][0]`).

**Approach:**

```
from itertools import groupby
data = {'sku1': 'k-1', 'sku2': 'k-2', 'sku3': 'b-10', 'sku4': 'b-1', 'sku5': 'x-1', 'sku6': 'x-2'}
result = {key: dict(group) for key, group in groupby(data.items(), lambda pair: pair[1][0])}
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'k': {'sku1': 'k-1', 'sku2': 'k-2'},
 'b': {'sku3': 'b-10', 'sku4': 'b-1'},
 'x': {'sku5': 'x-1', 'sku6': 'x-2'}}
```